# Python aiogram 2.25.2 ошибка TypeError: Object of type InlineKeyboardButton is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

помогите исправить ошибку TypeError: Object of type InlineKeyboardButton is not JSON serializable

main.py:

```
from config import TOKEN
from logging import basicConfig, INFO
from buttons import *

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
basicConfig(level=INFO)

@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Добро пожаловать в бота!', reply_markup=button_1)


@dp.message_handler(text='Кнопка 1')
async def button1(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Ответ на кнопку 1')

@dp.message_handler(text='Кнопка 2')
async def button1(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Ответ на кнопку 2')

@dp.message_handler(text='Кнопка 3')
async def button1(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Ответ на кнопку 3')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

buttons.py:

```
from aiogram import types

button_1l = [
    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 1'),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 2'),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 3')
]

button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(button_1l)
```

После запуска бота и ввода /start возникает ошибка TypeError: Object of type InlineKeyboardButton is not JSON serializable

Смотрел в интернете решение, но ничего особо полезного не нашел. Пытался перейти на aiogam 3.2 но там возникли другие ошибки

Python: 3.10.2
Aiogam: 2.25.2

Comment: В каком месте кода возникает ошибка?

Comment: В buttons.py на последней строке, где идет InlineKeyboardMarkup, именно когда я пишу боту /start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## main.py:

```
from aiogram import *
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

from config import TOKEN
from logging import basicConfig, INFO

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
basicConfig(level=INFO)

keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
b1 = InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 1", callback_data="fun1")
b2 = InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 3", callback_data="fun2")
b3 = InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка 4", callback_data="fun3")

keyboard.add(b1, b2, b3) #так вы их разместите в ряд 

@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Добро пожаловать в бота!', reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.startswith('fun1'))
async def fun1(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ответ на кнопку 1'")

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.startswith('fun2'))
async def fun2(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ответ на кнопку 2'")

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.startswith('fun3'))
async def fun3(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ответ на кнопку 3'")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Файл buttons.py вам не нужен
Если будут вопросы, или где-то допущена моя ошибка(вроде нету), я с удовольствием отвечу в коментариях

Comment: Благодарю! Все работает

Comment: рад помочь, единственное, что добавлю о кнопках, Вы должны всегда передавать что-то в кнопках либо ссылку либо название функции, тоесть пустую кнопку создать не получиться. как в вашем примере